# bash: adding elements to array

Tags: arrays, bash

in this code i just save paths into array#1. This array works fine:

```
echo "Searching for *omd*-paths..."
cd /

# creating array#1
all_omd_paths=`find -type d -name omd`
```

Ok, but now i want to put specific paths into another array (array#2):

```
for path in $all_omd_paths
do
        if [[ $path == *"s"* ]]; then
            # fill array#2
            omd_sites_paths+=($path)
        fi
done

for path in $omd_sites_paths
do
    # wrong output
    echo $path
done
```

With the second for-loop i just get ONE path on output... But i know there are more saved in array#1. What s wrong with array#2? How do i fill it correctly?

Comment: Your creating array#1 is downright wrong. It doesn't create an array. And when accessing all array elements in bash, you need `"${omd_site_paths[@]}"`. Moreover, the entire thing is not safe at all against whitespaces and special characters  in paths.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. Do you have a hint or keyword for getting the paths out of 'find'-command?

Comment: Use `find -print0` and a `while read` loop. See BashFAQ/001: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#CA-fbb19f8681e0b417dcf3270add51d49ddbb14be9 . Carefully replicate all the options to both commands! They are all vital in ensuring robustness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $omd_sites_paths is an array:

```
for path in ${omd_sites_paths[@]}
```